# Debezium SqlServerConnector ( No maximum LSN recorded in the database )

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, apache-camel, debezium, cdc

I have an application with CDC (Change Data Capture) implemented using Debezium Embedded and built with Apache Camel. While analyzing the pod logs, everything seemed to be functioning correctly until at one point I started receiving this warning log repeatedly.

```
2023-09-18 08:16:34.032 WARN 1 --- [rce-coordinator] .c.s.SqlServerStreamingChangeEventSource : No maximum LSN recorded in the database; please ensure that the SQL Server Agent is running
```

Do you know if this issue is stemming from the Debezium connector configurations, or if it is a problem on the SQL Server side? Has anyone encountered this before? (Note: I am using the Debezium SQL Server connector).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: I realized that the problem was that DBZ had finished capturing all the changes, and there were no more changes to capture in the db and the log misled me. I thought I had more talking log.

Thank you for your attention as always.